# Weird gridview behaviour

Tags: c#, android, gridview, xamarin

I try to be more clear in titles... but... this is just weird...

1st: The setup

Working with Xamarin. I have 2 grid views. The 1st one is created and populated when the application opens. The 2nd one is created and populated when an item in the 1st grid view is clicked

Both gridviews are created with the same contructor and the same adapter classes.

2nd: The issue

The 1st thing I noticed was that when the second gridview was created, the 1st item of the 1st gridview would dissapear. Regardless of where I would click. With both grids visible the app looks like this:

[image]

Its easy to make it reappear, I just need to add a `adapter.NotifyDatasetChanged()` to the behaviour that makes the 1st cell dissapear and the cell never dissapers. Great... altough its a patch, not a solution, and this patch is not good enough when there's a lot of grid creation going on. Moreover, I also noticed that if I scroll down and back up, the cell would also reappear (likely because the view is forced to refresh the initial views when they come back to visible range). I figured my issue was the implementation of my custom adapter. Thus, I spent a decent amount of time looking at my GetView implementation. Then I noticed something weirder: If I scroll down and then back up the views refresh, just as I said before, however, if I only scroll a little, like halfway down the cell that is no longer visible, and then back up, this happens:

[image]

Yeah... it kinda keeps scrolling up forever. Is the problem still my adapter implementation?

My GetView is pretty simple, I have a separated list with views and the GetView fetchs the required view there:

```
        public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            RelativeLayout temp;
            if (convertView != null) {
                temp = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
            } else {
                temp = new CustomGestureListener (Android.App.Application.Context);
            }
            temp.RemoveAllViews ();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams cellLP = null;
            if (data [position] != null) {
                RelativeLayout referenceView = (RelativeLayout)data [position].NativeObj;
                if(referenceView != null && referenceView.Handle != IntPtr.Zero){
                    View refParent = (View)referenceView.Parent;
                    if (refParent != null)
                        ((ViewGroup)refParent).RemoveView (referenceView);

                    cellLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, referenceView.LayoutParameters.Height);//(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)referenceView.LayoutParameters;
                    temp.AddView (referenceView, cellLP);
                }
            }

            return (View)temp;
        }
```

I have been using the same adapter in my listviews without issues. Even if I replace the 1st grid by a Listview with this same adapter and I recreate this behaviour of creating a gridview, the issue does not happen in the ListView